# Populating a treeview with XSD retrieved from XML column using linq

Tags: wpf, xml, linq, xaml, xsd

I have a xml column containing the content of loaded xsd files. I am using linq to retrieve the files

```
var xsd = from r in RegulatoryAuthoritySchema
    where r.XsdTypeID == 2
    where r.MajorSchemaVersion == 1
    where r.MinorSchemaVersion ==0
    where r.XsdStatusID == 2
    select r.XsdData;
```

My first issue is that I can return the xsd as a string but not as a well formed xml object.

For example, if I try to parse it as an XElement or XMLDocument I get 
'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.' 
I'm assuming this is due to it being derived from an xsd and not xml source. So XMLDocument expects a BOM in the declaration.

My second issue is using the returned xsd as a dynamic source for a WPF treeview. I have seen static examples of XSDs being displayed in a WPF treeview by defining them in the XData of an xmldataprovider resource in the XAML. The XMLDataprovider has a source property but this takes URIs or there is the document property that would take an XMLDocument if I could sort the first issue.

My application is WPF4 and uses MVVM so ideally the xsd would be represented as a property of a ViewModel which the treeview was then bound to, but thats another post.

Comment: What's your XML/XSD look like?  From memory you need to *remove* the encoding tag `<?xml version="1.0"` to Load into an XElement...

Comment: Yes your right I will give that a try and hopefully get the document loaded as an XElement.

Comment: When I run the above linq query in LINQPAD it returns a string starting with the schema's namespace declaration so I am assuming that this is what causes the error

Comment: The xsd was originally loaded from file as a XDocument that was then stored in an XML column using Xdocument.tostring() to provide the data.